# R console does not recognize the encoding of directly input text

Tags: r, encoding

I have been wondering why the text that is directly typed in an R script does not seem to be treated as UTF-8 encoded? The file itself is saved and opened in UTF-8. For example, the encoding of Chinese text strings mixed with numbers is displayed as unknown according to the result in the console.

```
> str <- c("字符編碼問題", "字符編碼問題1", "字符編碼問題2")
> Encoding(str)
[1] "unknown" "unknown" "unknown"
```

Using the `enc2utf8()` function to declare the encoding changes the encoding recognized in R.

```
> str_utf <- enc2utf8(str)
> Encoding(str_utf)
[1] "UTF-8" "UTF-8" "UTF-8"
```

This issue is affecting the use of text processing function such as `str_detect()` because the text stored inside the `txt_utf` object is UTF-8 encoded whereas the text in the script has an unknown encoding. Declaring the encoding of every single search string is cumbersome. So my question is: How can the text in the script be recognized as UTF-8 by default?

```
> str_detect(str, "題[:digit:]")
[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE

# fails to detect text patterns in the UTF-8 object
> str_detect(str_utf, "題[:digit:]")
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE

> str_detect(str_utf, enc2utf8("題[:digit:]"))
[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

My `R` session information is as follows:

```
R version 4.1.1 (2021-08-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19042)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Chinese (Traditional)_Hong Kong SAR.950  LC_CTYPE=Chinese (Traditional)_Hong Kong SAR.950   
[3] LC_MONETARY=Chinese (Traditional)_Hong Kong SAR.950 LC_NUMERIC=C                                       
[5] LC_TIME=Chinese (Traditional)_Hong Kong SAR.950    
system code page: 932
```

Comment: Can you post the the code that's actually causing the issue? The string "sdf" just has ASCII characters to no special encoding information is tracked. Encoding only starts to matter when you have characters outside the ASCII range. Note that the WIndows OS uses LATIN-1 as the default text encoding at the system level but yours seems to be set at codepage 932. Support for UTF-8 by default in R on Windows is still only experimental at this time.

Comment: @MrFlick Thank you for your comment. I've changed the text string examples to include some Chinese characters. The issue arises when text is store in UTF-8 encoding in an object (e.g., a tibble) whereas the text directly typed in the script as regular expressions does not seem to be recognized as UTF-8, which leads to the failure of text detection.